# How to create Login system in silverlight?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, silverlight, authentication

i am designing a silverlight application in which i want to level of user access:

```
Public and User
```

I want that

**Public** (wihout login) it can access two xaml page.

and

**User** can access other all the pages but for that he must be logged in the application.

*So for that i want to create login/registration system.
At the time of registration i want to store all the information of the user in SQL Server and letter want to use all those infomation at the time of loggin in.*

I have tried one or two tutorials about ASP.NET authentication but using this i can have only limited no. of user. Means i need to create users from ASP.NET configuration method. But i want as stated above.

How can i do that ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is little vague, but will try to answer it.

- You can use **Claim Base Authentication**. User will get a Claim to access a specific page. Doing so you can give very accurate access to user.
- You will need some **web services** (WCF, RIA etc) using which you can get and set data. These services will internally store your data in database.
- You can use **LINQ to SQL** or **Entity Base Model** to store and retrieve data from database. This will be your **DAL**.
- For **Authenticating user,** there are lots of ways, easiest will be you take user information, like name, email etc. and keep email as token to identify unique user. To validate this email address you can send an email with a verify link. Other options can be, (I will prefer this) **Open Id**. User will use there Open Id to authenticate themselves. This is little difficult to implement, but depending upon application you can for this. The **advantage of Open Id** is user will not have to remember login credentials on your website.

Hope this info helps you.

Answer (score 0):

First you probably need some sort of data structure that describe the state of the User. e.g. User's login status, user permission level, username, etc. And you would set these properties of the User depending on what returned from the authentication process (checking if the username and password match with the database).

Once that is completed, you can check for the user's login status and permission level to see if the user is allowed to view each of the restricted pages, otherwise popup an alert or redirect the user to a public page.